# Counterclockwise and :gen-class

Tags: eclipse, clojure, counterclockwise

I'm using Eclipse (4.2.0) with Counteclockwise (0.10.1.STABLE001). I have a clojure namespace for which I would like to generate a class:

```
(ns a.b.c
  (:gen-class
   :name "a.b.c.Service"))

 (-method [] ...)
```

There is a defect, but it's marked as fixed as of version 0.59 [here](http://code.google.com/p/counterclockwise/issues/detail?id=7).

Is there a way that I can trigger or configure this from the IDE without resorting to a command-line compilation?

There is a related question, [How to use a compiled Clojure class in Eclipse with Counterclockwise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215406/how-to-use-a-compiled-clojure-class-in-eclipse-with-counterclockwise), but no solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Counterclockwise 0.10.1 (the version you're using), there is a simple way to do this: you have to start a launch configuration from the project's root node contextual menu (Run as > Clojure Application).

- When launched from the project root, the builder will be configured to AOT compile the whole project everytime you save a file (and also when the launch starts, tho it has sometimes proven working unreliably). This means your namespace will be AOT compiled, and thus your gen-class.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you are using CCW with leiningen and hence have a project.clj file:

add a like like this to project.clj:

```
:aot [org.example.sample]
```

You may not have a project.clj file if you used CCW to create the project

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using m2e. We have considered the possibility of using leiningen instead, but are not ready to give up the hierarchical functionality provided by maven.

Comment: leiningen is a wrapper around maven, it produces a pom file and then calls maven. (run lein pom)