# How to pass list as a parameter to a clojure function

Tags: clojure

How to pass list(collection) as a parameter to a clojure function, this clojure is called by java code.

Comment: please explain this stuff to me. ----------------------------------(ns utils
   (:gen-class :name Utils
               :methods [#^{:static true} [sum [java.util.Collection] long]]))

(defn sum [coll] (reduce + coll))

(defn -sum [coll] (sum coll))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clojure:

```
(ns utils ; Sets the namespace to utils
   (:gen-class :name Utils ; The keyword :gen-class declares that
                           ; I want this compiled as a class. The
                           ; :name declares the name (and the package)
                           ; of the class I want created. 
               :methods [#^{:static true} [sum [java.util.Collection] long]]))
                           ; In the vector following :methods I've declared
                           ; the methods I want to have available in the
                           ; generated class. So I want the function 'sum'
                           ; which takes a 'java.util.Collection' as an
                           ; argument and returns a value of type 'long'.
                           ; The metadata declaration '#^{:static true}
                           ; signals that I want this method to be declared
                           ; static.

; The Clojure function. Takes a collection and
; sums the values in the collection using 'reduce'
; and '+'.
(defn sum [coll] (reduce + coll))

; The wrapper function that is available to Java.
; Just calls 'sum'.
(defn -sum [coll] (sum coll))
```

Java:

```
public class CalculateSum {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    java.util.List<Integer> xs = new java.util.ArrayList<Integer>();
    xs.add(10);
    xs.add(5);
    System.out.println(Utils.sum(xs));
  }
}
```

This prints out 15.

Comment: ponzao, tell me the way to compile and run this code on window xp. javac -cp clojure.jar CalculateSum.java, java -cp clojure.jar CalclulateSum........will work?

Comment: D:\work\test-Clojure>javac -cp clojure.jar CalculateSum.java
CalculateSum.java:6: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable Utils
location: class CalculateSum
    System.out.println(Utils.sum(xs));
                       ^
1 error

D:\work\test-Clojure>

Comment: @vikbehal You can compile CalculateSum without the Clojure dependency, so `javac CalculateSum.java` is enought. Then you have to compile the Clojure source file. For instance in the repl with `(compile 'utils)`. Then just run it with the classpath properly set `java -cp .:../lib/clojure-1.2.1.jar CalculateSum` (this is on Linux).

Comment: @vikbehal You get the error because you have not compiled `utils.clj`.

Comment: thanx man, this is working fine now. I have one more question! link is here [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7659423/is-it-possible-to-pass-a-tree-data-structure-to-clojure-and-work-on-it)

Comment: @vikbehal I added comments, but I recommend you read the link given in mikera's post. I think it does a better job of explaining this than me.

Comment: @vikbehal If there isn't a question here already about creating a JAR file on Windows I recommend creating one. The answer to this is clearly out of the scope of your original question.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the great answers to the question on [calling clojure from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181774/calling-clojure-from-java)

There's nothing special particularly about a list: any Java object can be passed as a parameter to a Clojure function in the same way.

Comment: thankyou mikera, i tried to pass a list as a parameter but wasn't successful. if possible could you please give me a small sample program. (clj and java)?