# What does this clojure code do?

Tags: clojure

```
(ns utils
   (:gen-class :name Utils
               :methods [#^{:static true} [sum [java.util.Collection] long]]))

(defn sum [coll] (reduce + coll))

(defn -sum [coll] (sum coll))
```

Please explain this code!

Comment: Sure, do you want fries while you wait? Or put slightly less cynically: have you *tried* understanding it? What is your interpretation, where are you stuck?

Comment: This isn't homework by any chance, right? ;)

Comment: @Matt it is actually a copy-paste of my original answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7658954/how-to-pass-list-as-a-parameter-to-a-clojure-function

Comment: @Matt '(defn sum [coll] (reduce + coll))

(defn -sum [coll] (sum coll))' In this, first sum function is calculating the sum. 2nd sum function(-sum) is required but why? and both function names have to be same?

Comment: They don't have to be. You can rename the first sum to whatever you please. The -sum definition has to be named like this because of the `:methods ... [sum [java.util...]]` definition

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having not used the Clojure gen-class facilities, my answer might be a little fuzzy:

This will generate the necessary byte-code which is about equivilant to the following Java pseudo code:

```
class Utils {
  public static long sum(Collection coll) {
    // Here goes the necessary code to call  (sum coll)
    // through the Clojure runtime
  }
}
```

- `-sum` instructs Clojure to generate the Java method.
- `(sum coll)` is the call to the first definition of `sum`, which is just a regular Clojure function definition