# access clojure via java classes

Tags: java, functional-programming, clojure

Hello I have a main method in a Java class and I would like to access and run my clojure functions from my java classes, is that possible right?

Help please

Comment: I think you're mis-spelling something 'clojure'. Don't get it though, I say 'Yes'.

Comment: clojure is a JVM scripting language (Lisp like).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to call a function which you have defined in a Clojure script the following code might help you getting the job done:

**test.clj:**

```
(ns test)
(defn hello [name]
  (println (str "Hi " name "!")))
```

**TestRun.java:**

```
import clojure.lang.RT;
public class TestRun {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        RT.loadResourceScript("test.clj");
        // var(namespace, function name).invoke(parameters..)
        RT.var("test", "hello").invoke("Daisy Duck");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Hi Daisy Duck!
```

Make sure you have the Clojure jar on your classpath

Comment: In 2008 before clojure had ahead of time compilation this was the answer. It is terribly innefficient today. the correct answer is to compile a class with methods and call them from java as you would anything else. no need to compile at every run

Comment: Yep, you're certainly right. I prefer to optimize when speed becomes an issue ;)

Answer (score 2):

Do you have your Clojure code compiled and packaged in a jar? Do you have the jar in your classpath? If so, you should be able to use the classes in the jar just as if there were written in Java.

Answer (score 2):

see the accepted answer to this question: [Calling clojure from java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181774/calling-clojure-from-java)

in short you add the mothods you want to expose to your namespace:

```
(ns com.domain.tiny
  (:gen-class
    :name com.domain.tiny
    :methods [ [binomial [int int] double]]))
```

then write the functions. compile your class file with maven/leiningen

then call them from java:

```
System.out.println("(binomial 5 3): " + tiny.binomial(5, 3));
```

This is just an excerpt. take a look as the origional question.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Java Scripting API for calling functions in script files:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/index.html