# How do I implement a Java interface in Clojure

Tags: java, clojure

How do I create a Clojure object that implements this interface and then gets called from Java code?

```
public interface Doer {
   public String doSomethin(String input);
}

Doer clojureDoer = ?;

String output = clojureDoer.doSomethin(input);
```

Comment: thanks everyone for helping me out! i ended up using Reify and just wrote the main function in clojure. clojure is incredibly cool!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`reify` is strongly preferred for implementing interfaces - `proxy` is heavy-duty, old, and slow, so should be avoided when possible. An implementation would look like:

```
(reify Doer
  (doSomethin [this input]
    (...whatever...)))
```

Answer (score 19):

As of [Clojure 1.6](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/changes.md), the preferred approach would be as follows. Assuming you have, on your classpath, the Clojure 1.6 jar and the following clojure file (or its compiled equivalent):

```
(ns my.clojure.namespace
  (:import [my.java.package Doer]))

(defn reify-doer
  "Some docstring about what this specific implementation of Doer
  does differently than the other ones. For example, this one does
  not actually do anything but print the given string to stdout."
  []
  (reify
    Doer
    (doSomethin [this in] (println in))))
```

then, from Java, you could access it as follows:

```
package my.other.java.package.or.maybe.the.same.one;

import my.java.package.Doer;
import clojure.lang.IFn;
import clojure.java.api.Clojure;

public class ClojureDoerUser {
    // First, we need to instruct the JVM to compile/load our
    // Clojure namespace. This should, obviously, only be done once.
    static {
        IFn require = Clojure.var("clojure.core", "require");
        require.invoke(Clojure.read("my.clojure.namespace"));
        // Clojure.var() does a somewhat expensive lookup; if we had more than
        // one Clojure namespace to load, so as a general rule its result should
        // always be saved into a variable.
        // The call to Clojure.read is necessary because require expects a Clojure
        // Symbol, for which there is no more direct official Clojure API.
    }

    // We can now lookup the function we want from our Clojure namespace.
    private static IFn doerFactory = Clojure.var("my.clojure.namespace", "reify-doer");

    // Optionally, we can wrap the doerFactory IFn into a Java wrapper,
    // to isolate the rest of the code from our Clojure dependency.
    // And from the need to typecast, as IFn.invoke() returns Object.
    public static Doer createDoer() {
        return (Doer) doerFactory.invoke();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Doer doer = (Doer) doerFactory.invoke();
        doer.doSomethin("hello, world");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Gary Verhaegen ;)

Answer (score 15):

## With proxy

See the `proxy` macro. [Clojure Docs](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/proxy) have some examples. It's also covered on [Java Interop](http://clojure.org/java_interop#Java%20Interop-Implementing%20Interfaces%20and%20Extending%20Classes) page.

```
(proxy [Doer] []
  (doSomethin [input]
    (str input " went through proxy")))
```

`proxy` returns an object implementing `Doer`. Now, to access it in Java you have to use `gen-class` to make your Clojure code callable from Java. It's covered in an answer to the ["Calling clojure from java"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181774/calling-clojure-from-java) question.

## With gen-class

```
(ns doer-clj
  (:gen-class
    :name DoerClj
    :implements [Doer]
    :methods [[doSomethin [String] String]]))

(defn -doSomethin
  [_ input]
  (str input " went through Clojure"))
```

Now save it as `doer_clj.clj`, `mkdir classes` and compile it by calling in your REPL `(require 'doer-clj) (compile 'doer-clj)`. You should find `DoerClj.class` ready to be used from Java in `classes` directory

Comment: Note "Doer clojureDoer = ?" in my question.  What do I put into "?" to make the program work.  The link you give shows how to import a clojure object as a static class. Thanks!

Comment: In such case you might be more interested in the second half of my answer that I've just added. It's `proxy`-free and seems way more adequate to your case. I think I'll delete the first half if the second one solves your problem.

Comment: Interesting..  I  had to put Doer into a package, because the compiler was looking for java.lang.Doer otherwise. I got an exception Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Duplicate method name&signature in class file DoerClj when I do Doer doer = new DoerClj();

Comment: Just to clarify - which Clojure version are you using?

Comment: Strange. Try to compile this simple [example](http://pastebin.com/6r7a31pf) based on [`Runnable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) interface. When I `(require 'doer-clj) (compile 'doer-clj)` I can call `DoerClj.run()` without any problems.

Comment: Clojure 1.3.0 stable has been released.

Answer (score 10):

For a more general take on this question, this diagram can be freaking useful when you are in need for some kind of Java-interop:

https://github.com/cemerick/clojure-type-selection-flowchart

Comment: I ran into that once before, but I didn't realized how good of a resource it really is. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

If `doSomethin()` is defined in your interface, you should **not** mention it in `:methods`. Quote from http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/gen-class:

```
:methods [ [name [param-types] return-type], ...]
The generated class automatically defines all of the non-private
methods of its superclasses/interfaces. This parameter can be used
to specify the signatures of additional methods of the generated
class. Static methods can be specified with ^{:static true} in the
signature's metadata. Do not repeat superclass/interface signatures
here.
```