# Clojure Storm Flux

Tags: clojure, apache-storm, apache-storm-flux

I started to work with [Apache Storm](http://storm.apache.org/) recently. I use Storm with [Clojure Storm DSL](http://storm.apache.org/releases/1.0.1/Clojure-DSL.html) and [Leiningen](http://leiningen.org/).

There is a very cool tool for storm topology management: [Storm Flux](https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/external/flux).

My question is: How can I use flux when I am coding in storm with clojure?

Comment: I am not sure, but I guess you need to compile your clojure code into class files (for each spout, bolt) so you can use those class files within flux.

Comment: Thanks @MatthiasJ.Sax, I try this solution but I miss something. In my ns I use :gen-class and I have my defspout macro for example. But the compiled file didn't take the IRichSpout object to generate the class :( Did you understand?

Comment: Or maybe you have a little example?

Comment: You need in inherit the interface using `reify`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614734/how-do-i-implement-a-java-interface-in-clojure

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax  what do you think about this solution? I couldn't use reify because I'll need a class before running time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
(ns your.namespace.boltname
  (:use
    [org.apache.storm clojure config])
  (:gen-class :implements [org.apache.storm.topology.IRichBolt]))

(defbolt my-bolt
         ["data"]
         [tuple collector]
         (emit-bolt! collector [(f (.getString tuple 0))] :anchor tuple)
         (ack! collector tuple))

(defn -execute [this tuple]
 (.execute my-bolt tuple))

(defn -prepare [this conf context collector]
 (.prepare my-bolt conf context collector))

(defn -cleanup [this]
 (.cleanup my-bolt))

(defn -declareOutputFields [this output]
 (.declareOutputFields my-bolt output))

(defn -getComponentConfiguration [this]
 (.getComponentConfiguration my-bolt))
```

don't forget to add `:aot :all` to `your project.clj`.

And in your flux `topology.yaml` something like:

```
...
bolts:
  - id: "myBolt"
    className: "your.namespace.boltname"
    parallelism: 1
...
```

That's all :)

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax what do you think about this solution? I couldn't use reify because I'll need a class before running time