# Dynamically computing gen-class

Tags: clojure

Clojure's java interop is good but often bridging between an object oriented java API (especially one requiring subclassing, annotations, and state) and clojure code is awkward. To make this easier, I had a thought to try to provide a wrapper such that I could write something like this:

```
(component "Foo"
   (handler "bar"))
```

and by implementing `component` and `handler` as macros I could return something uglier but correct like:

```
(gen-class
  [component-name]
  :name ^{Component {}} (str "com.foobar." component-name)
  :implements [com.foobar.api.SomeInterface]
  :main false
  :constructors {[com.foobar.data.SomeData]} []}
  ...
```

However, while it appears that my `component` macro would expand to the code above, `gen-class` appears to be a special form that is sought during compilation and parsed without evaluating its "child forms". This means that forms like `(str "com.foobar." component-name)` are not evaluated and the generated class is actually `./(str "com/foobar/" name).class`

Is there anyway I can create a little DSL to generate java classes like this?

Comment: You mean something like `reify`? https://stackoverflow.com/a/8615002/1027568

Comment: No - I'm asking about generating a java class file at compile time to be loaded into a java application as an extension

Comment: Which is what `reify` and `proxy` already do for you, so why would you want to make yet another one? What does not seem to work for you with either `reify` or `proxy`? By the way, if you are using `macros`, you are anyway running at compile time and not at runtime, so I really dont understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Maybe this will help a bit https://chasemerick.files.wordpress.com/2011/07/choosingtypeforms2.png

Comment: Maybe I have misunderstood but I thought reify and proxy only generated runtime java instances, not static .class files. Am I wrong?

Comment: you can preprocess the topmost macro form to `macroexpand-all` internal macro calls you need. (if i remember correctly, this approach was demonstrated in 'on lisp' or 'let over lambda').. maybe pre/postwalk-replace could help

Comment: If I understood correctly, the `gen-class` is inside a macro, so it would be nice if you share the macro code. If you have something like `\`(gen-class ... :name ~(str "a.b" name)`, then, probably, you're missing the tilde.

Comment: Aha, ok thanks @ThiagoLewin - I think this is what I needed. I will read up on the tilde (unquote).

Comment: @Marplesoft Take a look at this chapter from a really good clojure book for writing macros: https://www.braveclojure.com/writing-macros/

Comment: You can also find a function that does what you want if you go to see the source code of the macro `gen-class`: https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/genclass.clj#L637