# Can In Gradle mix .java and .clojure and .scala files

Tags: java, scala, gradle, clojure

Can In Gradle mix .java and .clojure and .scala files. I want to mix few programming languages, just searching best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm starting with a project with mixed java, scala and clojure.
In order to include scala I simply added the [scala plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/scala_plugin.html)

`apply plugin: 'scala'`

and the scala dependency to dependencies section:

`compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.7'`

To include clojure I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29018574/1195507).

My final `build.gradle` file looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://clojars.org/repo" }
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'clojuresque:clojuresque:1.7.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'scala'
apply plugin: 'clojure'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://clojars.org/repo" }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.clojure:clojure:1.7.0'
    compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.7'
}

// NOTE: You *must* enable AOT (Ahead-of-Time) compilation in order to use a Clojure class as the main class
clojure.aotCompile = true
clojure.warnOnReflection = true

mainClassName = "foo"
```

My project structure is this one:

```
.
├── build.gradle
└── src
    └── main
        ├── clojure
        │   └── foo.clj
        ├── java
        │   └── JavaClass.java
        └── scala
            └── HelloWorld.scala
```

and after run `gradle build` I'm getting this build folder:

```
 build
 ├── classes
 │   └── main
 │       ├── HelloWorld$.class
 │       ├── HelloWorld.class
 │       ├── JavaClass.class
 │       ├── foo$_main.class
 │       ├── foo$fn__64.class
 │       ├── foo$loading__5340__auto____62.class
 │       ├── foo.class
 │       └── foo__init.class
 ├── dependency-cache
 ├── distributions
 │   ├── init-proj-1.0.0.tar
 │   └── init-proj-1.0.0.zip
 ├── libs
 │   └── init-proj-1.0.0.jar
 ├── scripts
 │   ├── init-proj
 │   └── init-proj.bat
 └── tmp
     ├── compileJava
     │   └── emptySourcePathRef
     ├── compileScala
     └── jar
         └── MANIFEST.MF
```

I haven't reach the point of interop (calling clojure from scala and viceversa, [it is discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928872/clojure-and-scala-interop)), but at least it is generating the `.class` files.