# Using one-jar to build one jar file

Tags: java, jar, clojure, onejar

I'm trying to use one-jar to generate one jar file that contains clojure jar file and java class file: [Creating one jar file that for execution from Java/Clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12341993/creating-one-jar-file-that-for-execution-from-java-clojure)

Following [the instruction](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=getting-started&file=quickstart), I could generate directories using `one-jar-appgen-0.97.jar`. As instructed, I replaced the java source, and added the `ThingOne-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar`

Running `ant`, it builds jar file without an error, but I got error messages when I try to  execute the jar file.

```
java -jar build/test-one-jar.jar 
test_one_jar main entry point, args=[]
Hello from Java!
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot.run(Boot.java:342)
    at com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot.main(Boot.java:168)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at clojure.lang.Namespace.<init>(Namespace.java:34)
    at clojure.lang.Namespace.findOrCreate(Namespace.java:176)
    at clojure.lang.Var.internPrivate(Var.java:149)
    at ThingOne.core.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at onejar.main.TestOneJarMain.run(TestOneJarMain.java:27)
    at onejar.main.TestOneJarMain.main(TestOneJarMain.java:20)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at clojure.lang.RT.lastModified(RT.java:374)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:408)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:398)
    at clojure.lang.RT.doInit(RT.java:434)
    at clojure.lang.RT.<clinit>(RT.java:316)
    ... 12 more
```

What might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Lines 168 and 342 in the Boot.java class of One-Jar indicate a problem with setting properties. This problem is happening when unit tests fail. My guess is it's related to [bug 3090800 in the SourceForge One-Jar Bug Tracker](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3090800&group_id=111153&atid=658457).