# How to set values in one ns from another ns?

Tags: parameters, clojure, namespaces, function

I have two namespaces: first is a gui in clojuresque java and second is in regular clojure. The user inputs values in the gui; these need to 'passed' to 'set' values in the the non-gui ns. I have read that using def within defn is bad practice even though it works. During my search to solve this wee problem I found the intern function. Is intern an acceptable solution or should I use something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yea, as the other answer pointed out, atoms are your best bet for maintaining mutable state.

Create an atom like:

```
(def my-state (atom 1))

(deref my-state)
=> 1

;; @ expands to a deref call
@my-state
=> 1
```

It can now be updated with swap:

```
(swap! my-state (fn [old-value] 2)
@my-state
=> 2
```

You can use this in a namespace that is callable from Java:

```
(ns foo.NonGUI
  (:gen-class
    :name foo.NonGUI
    :methods [#^{:static true} [setMyState [int] int]]))

(def my-state (atom))

(defn -setMyState
  "Set my state to new-value"
  [new-value]
  (swap! my-state (fn [old-value] new-value))
```

You should then be able to use this namespace from Java after compiling it and getting the compiled classfile on the java classpath:

```
import foo.NonGUI;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NonGUI.setMyState(4);
    }
}
```

See [Calling clojure from java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181774/calling-clojure-from-java) for more information on Java interop.

Comment: Thanks for this answer; it is spot-on for my program.

Comment: Done. Sorry to not do this before; it took me awhile to figure how to do the mark. I am not very familiar with these features.

Answer (score 0):

please use atom, doc from offical: http://clojure.org/atoms

Comment: I read the atom doc, but still not clear. An example would help me a lot. Thanks.

Comment: I think I have a solution (see answer), but I'm not sure why 'intern' is not OK. Solution using atom: user=> (def uat (atom 4) -> 4, user=> (in-ns 'ns2), ns2=> (clojure.core/reset! user/uat 7) -> 7, ns2=> @user/uat -> 7, (in-ns 'user) -> #<Namespace user>, user=> @uat -> 7