# Combinations of Map<Object, List<Object>>

Tags: java, hashmap, combinations

I have a `HashMap<GC, List<RR>>` with sample data like:

```
key   values

gc1 - rr1
    - rr2
    - rr3

gc2 - rr4
    - rr5

gc3 - rr6
```

And I need to create all possible combinations of RR from different GC like:

```
Combination1: rr1, rr4, rr6
Combination2: rr1, rr5, rr6
Combination3: rr2, rr4, rr6
Combination4: rr2, rr5, rr6
Combination5: rr3, rr4, rr6
Combination6: rr3, rr5, rr6
```

What I've tried so far is, as @Sanket Makani suggests, to turn my `HashMap<GC, List<RR>>` into a `List<List<RR>>`, and then iterate through all the elements like:

```
List<List<RR>> inputList = new ArrayList<List<RR>>();

for (Map.Entry<GC, List<RR>> rrList : Map.entrySet()) {
    inputList.add(rrList.getValue());
}

List<List<RR>> combinationsList = new ArrayList<List<RR>>();

for (List<RR> rrList : inputList) {
    List<RR> rrList1 = new ArrayList<RR>();
    for (RR rr : rrList) {
        rrList1.add(rr);
    }
    combinationsList.add(rrList1);
}
```

This is not working for me, as it groups all the RR inside one GC like:

```
Combination1: rr1, rr2, rr3
Combination2: rr4, rr5
Combination3: rr6
```

So my quesiton is, how can I adapt my code to obtain the expected result?

PS: I'm working with Java6 unfortunately, so no lambdas/streams allowed.

PS2: I've seen similar questions, but can't find and exact example of what I'm looking for.

EDIT:

This is my final implementation with @nandsito's answer:

```
//this method groups RRs by GC key with a given list
HashMap<GC, List<RR>> GCRRHashMap = groupRRsByGC(list); 

List<Map.Entry<GC, List<RR>>> mapEntryList = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<GC, List<RR>>>(GCRRHashMap.entrySet());
List<List<RR>> combinationsList = new ArrayList<List<RR>>();
List<RR> combinations = new ArrayList<RR>();

generateCombinations(mapEntryList, combinations, combinationsList);



private void generateCombinations(
  List<Map.Entry<GC, List<RR>>> mapEntryList, 
  List<RR> combinations, List<List<RR>> combinationsList) {

  if (mapEntryList.isEmpty()) {
    combinationsList.add(new ArrayList<RoomStay>(combinations)); 
    return;
  }

  Map.Entry<GC, List<RR>> entry = mapEntryList.remove(0);

  List<RR> entryValue = new ArrayList<RR>(entry.getValue());

  while (!entryValue.isEmpty()) {

    RR rr = entryValue.remove(0);

    combinations.add(rr);

    generateCombinations(mapEntryList, combinations, combinationsList);

    combinations.remove(combinations.size() - 1);
  }

  mapEntryList.add(0, entry);

}
```

Comment: You can store all the lists in `List<List<RR>>` then write a recursive algorithm which prints all the combinarion. You can store all the combinations in `ArrayList<StringBuilder>` and then print it.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov My 1st idea was to iterate through the Map.entrySet(), and then iterate internally through the List, but I don't see that working, as I would need X internal loops as keys x values I have.

Comment: There's difference between "that will not work" and "that will work very inefficiently".

Comment: By " I don't see that working" I mean, "I guess there probably are better solutions fro my problem". It's a made up phrase, sorry the meaning could be misunderstood.

Comment: For combinations: http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/Combinations.java.html

Comment: For permutations, which is what I think you want: http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/Permutations.java.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a recursive solution:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // your data map
    Map<GC, List<RR>> map;

    // the map entry set as list, which will help
    // combining the elements
    //
    // note this is a modifiable list

    List<Map.Entry<GC, List<RR>>> mapEntryList =
            new ArrayList<Map.Entry<GC, List<RR>>>(map.entrySet());

    // the combinations list, which will store
    // the desired results

    List<RR> combinations = new ArrayList<RR>();

    doRecursion(mapEntryList, combinations);
}

private static void doRecursion(
        List<Map.Entry<GC, List<RR>>> mapEntryList,
        List<RR> combinations) {

    // end of recursion

    if (mapEntryList.isEmpty()) {

        // do what you wish
        //
        // here i print each element of the combination

        for (RR rr : combinations) {

            System.out.println(rr);
        }

        System.out.println();

        return;
    }

    // remove one GC from the entry list,
    // then for each RR from the taken GC
    //     put RR in the combinations list,
    //     call recursion
    //     the remove RR from the combinations list
    // end for each
    // then put GC back into its list

    Map.Entry<GC, List<RR>> entry = mapEntryList.remove(0);

    List<RR> entryValue = new ArrayList<RR>(entry.getValue());

    while (!entryValue.isEmpty()) {

        RR rr = entryValue.remove(0);

        combinations.add(rr);

        doRecursion(mapEntryList, combinations);

        combinations.remove(combinations.size() - 1);
    }

    mapEntryList.add(0, entry);
}
```

Comment: I think you could lose the "initialize data" section, and it would make a better answer.

Comment: @slim yeah, it looks better, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: What I can't see, is how a List<RR> can give me the expected output, as the output should be a list of combinations, and not a list of elements

Comment: Also, this algorithm returns an empty combinations list

Comment: @ManuelS. every time the recursion reaches its end, `combinations` will have a valid combination. For your example, the recursion will end six times. So, to store all possible combinations, you can store a copy of `combinations` in a structure outside of the recursion every time the recursion ends

Comment: @ManuelS. did you properly initialize `map`?

Comment: @nandsito Ok, I now see about the lists, so before the return, I add to a `List<List<RoomStay>> combinationsList` the combinations list. But the algorithm still returns empty combinations list. I've checked my map and it's correctly initialized, and the mapEntryList correctly created from the map.

Comment: @ManuelS. could you please post the code somewhere so i could take a look?

Comment: @nandsito I've added an edit with my current code trying you approach

Comment: @ManuelS. add a copy of `combinations` to `combinationsList` instead of `combinations` itself, or else the same mutable object will be added multiple times. At the end of the recursion `combinations` will be empty indeed

Comment: something like `combinationsList.add(new ArrayList<RoomStay>(combinations));` ??

Comment: @ManuelS. yes, a shallow copy should do it

Comment: @nandsito That seems to do the trick!  Thank you! Do you want to edit your answer to match the final implementation, so I can mark it as correct answer?

Comment: @ManuelS. i'd rather keep my answer as it is, for it shows a solution for the combination problem in an abstract level. The way the solution is used, that is, the way the recursion result is collected, depends on who will use my algorithm. So, for the community benefit instead of a specific case, i'll leave my answer that way. Anyway i'm glad i could help

Comment: @nandsito Sounds good, I'll post my final implementation in the question edit. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

All you really need to do is work through an incrementing index list:

```
0,0,0
0,1,0
1,0,0
1,1,0
2,0,0
... etc.
```

It should be obvious how to translate each of those rows into to values from your data structure. e.g. `0,0,0` maps to `rr1, rr4, rr6`. This will involve converting the map into a list so that indexes are consistent.

It's very much like a normal base-b count where you increment the rightmost column and if it overflows, set to zero and increment the next one. The only difference is that each column overflows at a different number.

So:

```
boolean increment(int[] indexes) {
   int column = 0;
   while(true) {
      indexes[column]++;
      if(indexes[column] <  numberOfRRsInColumn(column)) {
         return true;  // finished
      }
      indexes[column]=0;
      column++;
      if(column = indexes.length) {
         return false; // can't increment, no more.
      }
   }
}
```

This implementation uses `indexes[0]` as the "rightmost" column. I've glossed over `numberOfRRsInColumn()`, but it should be pretty obvious how to do it.

Then:

```
int[] indexes = new int[mapsize];
do {
    output(translate(map, indexes));
} while (increment(indexes));
```

Comment: What do you mean by translate(map, indexes)?

Comment: @ManuelS. it's the translation from `[x,y,z]` to `data[0][x], data[1][y], data[2][z]` which I describe earlier as "should be obvious how to...". Is anything about it not obvious enough?