# Clojure and Java interoperation: Java.math.BigInteger

Tags: java, clojure, interop

I have a clojure code that has an output of BigInteger.

```
(ns com.domain.tiny
  (:gen-class
    :name com.domain.tiny
    :methods [#^{:static true} [binomial [int int] java.math.BigInteger]]))

(defn binomial
  "Calculate the binomial coefficient."
  [n k]
  (let [a (inc n)]
    (loop [b 1
           c 1]
      (if (> b k)
        c
        (recur (inc b) (* (/ (- a b) b) c))))))

(defn -binomial
  "A Java-callable wrapper around the 'binomial' function."
  [n k]
  (binomial n k))

(defn -main []
  (println (str "(binomial 5 3): " (binomial 5 3)))
  (println (str "(binomial 10042 111): " (binomial 10042 111)))
)
```

Executing it as a stand alone, I could get the result without an issue:

```
(binomial 5 3): 10
(binomial 10042 111): 
4906838957506814494663377752836616342 ...
48178314846156008309671682804824359157818666487159757179543983405334334410427200
```

I could generate jar file with `lein uberjar`. Trying to use it from Java, I came up with this code.

```
import com.domain.tiny;
import java.math.BigInteger;
public class Hello
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigInteger res = tiny.binomial(5, 3);
        System.out.println("(binomial 5 3): " + res);
        res = tiny.binomial(10042, 111);
        System.out.println("(binomial 10042, 111): " + res);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I got exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast 
    to java.math.BigInteger
at com.domain.tiny.binomial(Unknown Source)
at Hello.main(Hello.java:11)
```

How can I interoperate clojure and Java for Java.Math.BigInteger? I could use `:methods [#^{:static true} [binomial [int int] double]]))` and `double res = tiny.binomial(10042, 111);` but not BigInteger.

This is the step that I took to get the jar and execute the java.

```
lein new com.domain.tiny
copy the tiny.clj in com.domain
lein deps
lein uberjar
javac -cp .:com.domain.tiny-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar Hello.java
java -cp .:com.domain.tiny-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar Hello
```

The clojure code is copied from: [Calling clojure from java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181774/calling-clojure-from-java)

Comment: Clojure is freaking cool.

Comment: Have you tried actually returning a java.math.BigInteger? (java.math.BigInteger. "123123123")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return value should have been clojure.lang.BigInt.

#### Clojure code

```
:methods [#^{:static true} [binomial [int int] clojure.lang.BigInt]]))
(defn binomial
  "Calculate the binomial coefficient."
  [n k]
  (let [a (inc n)]
    (loop [b 1
           c 1]
      (if (> b k)
        (bigint c) ;; <-- Without this code 
                   ;; java.lang.ClassCastException: 
                   ;; java.lang.Long cannot be cast to clojure.lang.BigInt occurs
        (recur (inc b) (* (/ (- a b) b) c))))))
```

#### Java code

```
import clojure.lang.BigInt;
...
BigInt res = tiny.binomial(10042, 111);
System.out.println("(binomial 10042, 111): " + res.toString());
```

#### Result

```
java -cp .:com.domain.tiny-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar Hello
>>> 
(binomial 5 3): 10
(binomial 10042 111): 49068389575068144946 … 27200
```