# Java passing custom objects to Clojure

Tags: java, clojure

I have a .java file that will be called for its `public String solve()` method to answer a problem. The method receives project-defined Java class RP, which contains a collection of RF, which each contain a collection of RO, which each contain several RA which, finally, boil down to String, String pairs (a name and a value). My question is, (how) can I have that solve() method pass its RP object to Clojure where I believe I can do all the work to generate a solution more effectively, and eventually return a String solution back?

**EDIT**: What I'm looking for is some way of saying, `String answer = toClojure(RP);` and in Clojure I'll be able to do the equivalent of RP.getRF().getRO().getRA().getName(), where each of these functions is defined in the Java classes.

Comment: Add some code to better understanding ..

Comment: @Jani we're talking about nested data structures here, so I'm not sure what code to give. There are four classes here which, along with some functions, basically boil down to: Collection[Collection[Collection[Collection <String, String>]]]. I need to pass the top-level one to Clojure and be able to get at the lower levels as needed.

Comment: Calling clojure from java http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181774/calling-clojure-from-java?rq=1

Comment: @edbond I've gone through that one; the major difference here is that I'm not passing primitives to Clojure; I'm passing a layered object, and I'm not sure how to do that or deal with it.

Comment: I don't see the difference. You can import RP and call (.. rp .getRF .getRO .getRA .getName)

Comment: @edbond You want `(-> rp .getRF .getRO .getRA .getName)`, or `(.. rp getRF getRO getRA getName)` if you insist on using `..`: the `.` interop is added automatically by `..`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass it the object reference, same as you would pass it to a java method. Clojure doesn't need any special magic to receive java objects.