# Returning Vectors, Sequences and Maps from Clojure to Java

Tags: java, clojure, interop

I've read the excellent answer to [Calling clojure from java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181774/calling-clojure-from-java) which shows the new style of calling Clojure from Java.

But the example given just returns a float. How can I return Clojure Vectors and other Sequence types from Clojure to Java? And Maps?

Specifically in this gen-class :

```
(ns dummy-app.core
  (:gen-class
   :name com.example.dummy
   :methods [#^{:static true} [f [int] int]
             #^{:static true} [getVect [] XXXX]
             #^{:static true} [getMap [] YYYY]
             #^{:static true} [getSeq [] ZZZZ]
             ] ))
```

what should I put for XXXX, YYYY and ZZZZ? And what types should they be in my Java program?

Update : in response to Tomo's promising answer, if I try to just use IPersistentVector in the gen-clas I get

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.IPersistentVector
```

when I try to create the Uberjar. I assume there's something else I need to do to import these types?

Update 2 : OK, thanks to more comments from Tomo this seems to work :

```
(ns dummy-app.core
  (import clojure.lang.IPersistentVector)
  (:gen-class
   :name com.example.dummy
   :methods [#^{:static true} [f [int] int]
             #^{:static true} [getVect [] clojure.lang.IPersistentVector]
             ] ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use appropriate interfaces: `IPersistentMap`, `IPersistentVector`, `ISeq` and so on. Check out the source code (https://github.com/clojure/clojure/tree/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang).

Comment: Thanks. But still not working for me. I updated the question with the extra details.

Comment: Well, I guess you need to import appropriate Java classes, with :import clause on the ns macro, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can also just specify the appropriate Java interfaces.

Clojure vectors, list and seqs all implement `java.util.List`

Clojure maps implement `java.util.Map`

Functions implement both `java.util.concurrent.Callable` and `java.lang.Runnable`