# Integrate Spring-based Java application and Clojure library

Tags: spring, clojure, redis, rmi, carmine

We have a Spring 4.0-based web application running in Tomcat 8 (alternatively we have a start-up script for Undertow). Spring MVC is handling requests. I am looking for a way to defer some of request handling code to Clojure library, with minimal changes to legacy Java code.

For instance, requests with URLs ending with `.java` would be handled by legacy Java, and requests ending with `.clj` would be handled by Clojure. For now, i see three options:

1. Include Clojure library jar in Java project's dependencies and use `clojure.java.api` to invoke Clojure code from Java.
2. Use some sort of RPC/RMI or message queues, e.g. Redis and Carmine's message queue processing capabilities. This way, Clojure would live in a separate JVM.
3. Use some sort of reverse proxy to perform URL routing.

Are above approaches actually feasible? What else would you suggest?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done a similar thing but on a DropWizard application rather than a Spring application. I went with approach #1.

I followed the example here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/2187427/827617
to create the library. That way you don't need to use `clojure.java.api`, your Clojure library compiles down into a jar that you can include in your Spring application and call directly from Java (the functions that you expose are static methods on a class).

Comment: Thanks, this is perhaps most convenient.