# How to make clojure code available in java?

Tags: java, gradle, clojure

In my Eclipse project I have the following Clojure code in `src/main/clojure/ext/clojuretest/helloworld.clj`:

```
(ns ext.clojuretest.helloworld)

;; https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/gen-class
(gen-class
  :name "ext.clojuretest.HelloWorld"
  :prefix "java-"
  :main true)

(defn java-main [& args]
  "I can say 'Hello World'."
  (println "Hello, World from Clojure!"))
  ;;(.println (System/out) "Hello, World from Java!"))
```

I'd like to use the class from Java code within the same project: `src/main/java/ext/clojuretest/ClojureTest.java`:

```
package ext.clojuretest;

public class ClojureTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HelloWorld h = new HelloWorld();
    }

}
```

I'm Building my Project with Gradle (`build.gradle`):

```
plugins {
  id "de.kotka.clojuresque.clojure" version "2.0.0"
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.clojure:clojure:1.8.0'
}

clojure.aotCompile = true
```

Is it somehow possible to use the class `HelloWorld` from within my Java code? Currently the compiler can't find `HelloWorld`

```
HelloWorld cannot be resolved to a type
```

Comment: Did you compile the clojure code?

Comment: Have you seen [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23555959/5044950) that details the preferred way to call Clojure from Java?

Comment: @cricket_007 In my Build-Script I tried: `compileJava.dependsOn compileClojure`

Comment: @SamEstep : I dont't see how this post can solve my problem. What is the `RT` and the `IFn` class for?; I also don't want to call a clojure function; I'd like to generate a class (which actually implements a Java interface). And use a method of this class.

Comment: @Edward That answer specifically states that the `RT` class is not meant to be called directly. Also, if your goal is to implement a Java interface, why doesn't the `gen-class` in your question use `:implements`?

Comment: @SamEstep : I left that part out, to keep the example simple

Comment: @Edward The point is that your question makes it seem like the easiest solution to your problem would be to just put `(ns ext.clojuretest.helloworld) (defn foo [] (println "Hello, world!"))` in `helloworld.clj` and call that function from Java using the API detailed in the answer I linked. If, as your comments indicate, such a solution would *not* work in your case, you should replace the code currently in your question with something that demonstrates what you're really trying to do and why the linked answer doesn't apply.

Comment: @SamEstep : Apart from the best practice mentioned in the linked article -> Do you have any idea why my code is not working?

Comment: @Edward My guess is that, like cricket_007 said, you didn't compile your Clojure code correctly. Incidentally, as far as I am aware, although `gen-class` requires AOT compilation to work, the API detailed in Alex Miller's answer does not.