# Can core.logic be used from Java directly?

Tags: java, clojure, clojure-core.logic

Is it possible to gainfully use core.logic from Java code? If so, would greatly appreciate a simple example.  If not, could someone point to a pure-Java alternative?

Comment: Have you seen this answer?  Should be no problem.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181774/calling-clojure-from-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call clojure code directly from java and you can check the link *Alan Thomspon* suggested in the comments, but I'm not sure if it will be very convenient to work with (I guess it will not).

Alternatively, as described on the [core.logic](https://github.com/clojure/core.logic) github repo:

> At its heart is an original implementation of miniKanren

On the [miniKanren implementations page](http://minikanren.org/#implementations) there are listed two java implementations.

You can check the [core tests of java8kanren](https://github.com/heidisu/java8kanren/blob/master/src/test/java/org/morkland/java8kanren/CoreTest.java) which have a fair amount of usage examples.