# Clojure, JavaFX Eventhandler not in namespace

Tags: javafx, clojure, event-handling, fxml

i'm trying to make a EventHandler for my FXML based View in my Clojure Projekt.
As described here: http://drowsy.de/blog/?p=7 i added in the FXML this

```
onAction="(use 'ui.listener) (add-tolist-listener event)"
```

to a button.

But when i launch the application i get following error message:

```
LoadException Error resolving onAction='(use 'ui.listener)
(add-tolist-listener event)', either the event handler is not in 
the Namespace or there is an error in the script.
```

In ui.listener is the eventhandler

```
(defn add-tolist-listener [event]
(println "I'm a Button"))
```

Any idea why this doesn't work?
I tried it with this notation

```
onAction = #add-tolist-listener
```

and it didn't worked too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am completely unfamiliar with JavaFX, however:

```
onAction="(use 'ui.listener) (add-tolist-listener event)"
```

This looks like Java code, so having Clojure syntax in here doesn't seem like it would work? I suspect you would have to call your Clojure code using Java?

Going off ["Calling Clojure code from Java"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181774/calling-clojure-from-java).

You would have to try something like:

```
ui.listener.add_tolist_listener
```

You might also find this blog post gives you another idea to try: [Invoking Clojure code from Java](https://clojurefun.wordpress.com/2012/12/24/invoking-clojure-code-from-java/).

Comment: ui.listener.add_tolist_listener doesn't work too...
No, i set up the gui only with Clojure, i don't call Clojure with Java

Answer (score 0):

Now is set up the action in my start function via

```
(.setOnAction (.lookup root "#startCalculationBtn")
  (proxy [EventHandler] []
    (handle [^ActionEvent event]
      (start-calculation))
    )
  )
```

And it works.