# import and use Clojure function more intelligently

Tags: java, clojure, leiningen

I have a Clojure project I created with `lein new`.  I have a junk.clj file with this

```
(ns myns.junk)

(defn sq [x] (* x x))
```

After loading the jar created by lein uberjar in my java project, I can import and call that function via

```
import myns.junk$sq;

public class JavaApplication1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(junk$sq.invokeStatic(5));       
    }  
}
```

My question is, is it possible to import that function more intelligently? Ie call it as a proper function, expecting an integer, and expecting to return an integer?

Comment: The first answer here looks like it should cover what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181774/calling-clojure-from-java

Comment: Thanks - vote to close as duo recorded - feel free to do likewise!