# Mixed Clojure and Java project in Maven

Tags: java, maven, clojure, clojure-maven-plugin

I have maven project, in directory `src/main/clojure` I have put code: https://github.com/8protons/url62/blob/master/src/url62/core.clj

I want to execute function `generate-id` in Java code from `src/main/java`.

```
IFn require = Clojure.var("clojure.core", "require");
require.invoke(Clojure.read("url62.core"));

IFn plus = Clojure.var("url62.core", "generate-id");
Object result = plus.invoke(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
System.out.println(result);
```

Maven configuration:

```
<package>jar</package>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.clojure</groupId>
        <artifactId>clojure</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.theoryinpractise</groupId>
            <artifactId>clojure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This compiles fine

```
target/classes/
├── core.clj
└── url62
    ├── core.clj
    ├── core$fn__3.class
    ├── core$generate_id.class
    ├── core__init.class
    ├── core$int_to_base62.class
    └── core$loading__5569__auto____1.class
```

but Java code fails:

```
clojure.lang.ArityException: Wrong number of args (1) passed to: core/generate-id

at clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity(AFn.java:429)
at clojure.lang.AFn.invoke(AFn.java:36)
at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:383)
at url62.Url62Test.name(Url62Test.java:17)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, clojoure function has no arguments :(

```
Object result = plus.invoke();
```