# If I have a simple Clojure print statement as a String in Java, how can I execute it with Clojure?

Tags: java, clojure

```
String printcode = "(print "foo")";
```

If I have the above String in java, is there anyway to execute it by clojure inside the Java ?

Comment: What does it mean to "have a string in Java?"  Can you be a bit more explicit?

Comment: @markspace just a simple String as my example. having the clojure code as a String

Comment: Someone who knows Clojure might understand, but I don't think Java programmers will.  You're literally asking how to execute the above single statement in Clojure?

Comment: why not just use `System.out.print(foo);`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling clojure from java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181774/calling-clojure-from-java)

Comment: i wrote that calling clojure form java question and that other question is asking the opposite of this one.

Answer (score 5):

The following should work (assuming that you have properly set up dependencies and initialised the Clojure runtime):

```
import clojure.lang.RT;
import clojure.lang.Compiler;

...

Compiler.eval(RT.readString("(print \"foo\")")));
```